# Receiving null in class fields on Kafka Listener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring kafka listener which receives custom java object. But for some reason, field of the received object is null.

My consumer configuration is :

```
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyObject> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConsumerFactory<String, MyObject> new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MyObject.class)
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyObject> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
}

 // props used above
 Map<String, Object> props = Map.of(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerServer,
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId,
            ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords,  
            ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollIntervalMs,
```

and my listener is here:

```
   @KafkaHandler
   public void listen( @Payload MyObject myobject)
```

What is wrong in my configuration so why deserializer cannot deserialize?

Comment: You need to show your `MyObject` class as well as a sample of the raw JSON in the topic.

Comment: actually found out that it correctly works but receives other type of objects and fails to serialize. Now my problem is how to stop consuming other kind of objects.